# Watir phantomjs returning empty response

Tags: ruby, phantomjs, watir

I'm using watir with phantomjs to write some automatic scripts. Here is the piece of code

```
require 'watir'

OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE


browser = Watir::Browser.new :phantomjs
browser.goto "https://google.com"
browser.html
```

It's returning empty response each time, it seems like it's not opening the page. So any help to fix that problem will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Development for PhantomJS has been suspended, so it may be difficult to find a solution. Ideally, you would use another browser. Perhaps try headless Chrome.

Comment: @JustinKo actually I have to run that script on ubuntu server & I don't have any browsers available there. Can you please recommend any other possible solution which I can apply so that the script run on server side.